# Where to put <thead>, <tbody> in a verticle heading table?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In a horizontal heading table, `<thead>` comes after the `<table>` and before `<tbody>` such as the following,

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">The table header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>The table body</td>
      <td>with two columns</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How about in a vertical heading table? What is the (best) practice to put the `<thead>`? I have seen the following without `<thead>`,

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>Name:</th>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Telephone:</th>
    <td>555 77 854</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Telephone:</th>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

I tried [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_headers) and [MDN The Table Head element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead), although it said `<thead>` is optional, is there any approach to include the element?

Comment: There's no `<thead>` in this case. Everything is in the`<tbody>`.

Comment: The <thead> must appear  before any <tbody>, <tfoot> and <tr> element.

Comment: @Paulie_D In a standard (default) horizontal `table` tag `thead` may appear before or after `tbody` and in any case renders as the table head. The same is true for `tfoot` tag. ;)

Comment: @kwok Use css to style first column as a header of your "vertical" table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any `<thead>`. However, for a vertical tables in particular, do not forget to [add the `scope` attribute to `<th>` cells](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H63.html):

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Name:</th>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Telephone:</th>
    <td>555 77 854</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Telephone:</th>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

(You can also omit the `<tbody>` if there's nothing else in the table)